# How do I refresh the relationships in a dataset?

Tags: visual-studio, dataset

I a working in VisualStudio 2005.  I have a dataset with sevaral datatables in it already. I had to modify the database to add a new foreign key that I forgot about.  How do I get visual studio to recognize the new relationship?

Answer (score 1):

.Net does not load FK relationships into your DataSet automatically - however, you can add them yourself with a [DataRelation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarelation.aspx)*.

*this may not be true if you are using LINQ - if you are, I am unsure.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the DataSet page, and select Add->Relation?

If you've defined it in your database, you can always re-drag the affected table back into the Dataset then re-enter your Queries.